# Can not get value for Select item?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, select

I can't seem to get the value for a 'selected item' to pass to a JavaScript function with PHP that uses the value to query data from MySQL database -> populates a different drop down list.

Here is my 'HTML' code

```
<select name="numbers" id="numbers" onChange="populateOtherSelect()">
   <option value="one">one</option>
   <option value="two">two</option>
   <option value="three">three</option>
   <option value="four">four</option>
</select>

<?php echo $option ?>
```

Here is my 'JavaScript' function code

```
function populateOtherSelect() {
 <?php
   // code that opens db connection

   $numbers = $_POST['numbers']; 

   $query = "select*from Database.Table where Something = 'Something' and Numbers like '%".$numbers."%'";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   $option = "";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $OtherOptions = $row["OtherOptions"];
        $option.="<option value=\"$OtherOptions\">".$OtherOptions."</option>\r\n";
    }

   // code that closes db connection
?>
```

}

Any information will be helpful.

Thanks very much

Comment: So what's the problem? Is the `$numbers` empty, or do you have a problem with the query?

Comment: If you want to do it like you have now, you have to post the form, which will cause the site to reload every time you change the list. Otherwise, it's AJAX.. have a look at the answer from @jeroen.

Comment: Yes I have looked at his answer. I am looking into AJAX now. I have not really looked at AJAX. I am new to programming. Thanks

Comment: To spell it out explicitly (since none of the other comments or answers seem to have done so yet): PHP code is run on the web-server before the page is downloaded to the user's web browser. JavaScript code is run in the web browser. This means that your JavaScript functions can't call your PHP functions and vice versa. As others have suggested, when your select element is changed you have to send another request to the web-server and either reload the whole page with your second select populated appropriately, or (the preferred way) go with AJAX to get the new data without reloading the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your javascript code is part of the html / php document and that´s not going to work; the php is run only at initial page-load and at that moment there probably is no `$_POST` variable.

What you need to do, is make an ajax call to a php script at the moment your first select is changed and use the response from that ajax call to populate your second select.

So basically your javascript function would have to look like:

```
function populateOtherSelect() {
  /*
   * 1. get the value of the numbers select
   * 2. make an ajax call to a php script / the server that gets some information from a database
   * 3. use the response from the ajax call to populate your second select
   */
}
```

Comment: +1 Just realized he had the `onChange` calling a php function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a space in your select statement:

```
$query = "select * from Database.Table where Something = 'Something' and Numbers like '%".$Numbers."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `$Numbers` variable doesn't exist, it's `$numbers`.

Comment: Well I change the code so it is easier to follow all the naming has the same case.